# what is edge-disjoint cycles in graph?

Tags: graphs, eulerian-paths

I was reading something about Eulerian Tour and there is one property claiming that:

> An undirected graph can be decomposed into edge-disjoint cycles if and only if all of its vertices have even degree.

Can someone explain what is edge-disjoint cycles?

[Wikipedia: Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A set of cycles $C$ of a graph $G=(V,E)$ is edge-disjoint if the cycles $c_i$, $c_j \in C$ have no edges in common.